# how to auto build jar by maven when i modify one java class?

Tags: maven, compiler-construction, m2eclipse

I have install m2eclipse plug-in for eclipse. I built a multi-module project by maven, each module are dependent, when i write a class,the eclipse can't automatically compile the class to jar file and install to M2 repository,i need to run MVN install command, then other modules can be reference the jar file, this is too much trouble, is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you seriously willing to wait several minutes while a full maven build occurs every time you save a change to a file in eclipse?

Comment: I use m2eclipse and don't need to do this; eclipse seems smart enough to know that a given module has it's dependencies locally so it doesn't go to .m2 to find it.  Perhaps in your build path add the maven project of the submodule as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the "install" phase does not belong to m2eclipse's [interesting lifecycle phases](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+build+lifecycle+mapping). In short, Eclipse and Maven build cycles differ a lot, and m2eclipse has a map that binds particular phases — and "install" is, by default, not mapped.

This map can be, however, configured in the POM of your project (ideally, the main POM). See: [M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)